# Launch Command Line Tool as detached Process

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Invoking a command line tool (`bash`, `ls`) via `Process` works, but unfortunately it is created as a child process.

I need to start the tool as a separate process, without adding it as a subprocess to my running application.

Therefore I tried to start a detached process of `bash` using launch services with

```
let ws = NSWorkspace.shared
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/bash")

let app = try ws.launchApplication(at: url, options: [.default], configuration: [
    .arguments: args,
    .environment: env
])
```

Unfortunately the call doesn't seem to do anything, I guess it only supports app bundles? How do I start a process, like e.g. `bash`, without creating a child process?

What I basically try to do is create a short-lived process that executes one thing and exits immediately without having my app as a parent.

One method would be to create a helper tool that `fork`s, starts a new session with `setsid` and invokes the command, but I'd prefer not to rely on an external tool, and forking my own process is out of the question. It is crucial that the invocation is done from a process with `ppid=1`.

Comment: Perhaps `NSUserUnixTask` is what you need.

Comment: Looks good, but i cant seem to find an option to pass environment vars or a working dir to `NSUserUnixTask`

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can't create a process that isn't a child process. The only process that's not a child process is the bootstrap kernel process (PID 0). Every other process is a child of some other process.

You can accomplish this by starting the executable running using a `Process` object (formerly `NSTask`) (the easy way) or with one of the traditional UNIX functions (`execle()` et. al.), and then just let it run.

The only thing you have to do is make sure your child process isn't tied to anything that would cause it to block or stop when your application terminates. Most notably, connect `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` to nothing (see `NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithNullDevice`) or something like a file or pipe that is not controlled by your process.

Start the executable (`task.lanch()`) and then simply discard the `Process` object; it will continue running on its own.

Comment: how does that answer my question? I need it not to be a child of my process, despite my app still running.

Comment: As I said, there's no such thing. ;) Every process has a PPID (Parent Process ID) and is therefor a "child" of the process that started it.

Comment: ok... then how do you explain more than one process running on a system? i'm prefectly aware that every process has a parent, but it should not be MY APP. ever heard of `fork/setsid`?

Comment: If your process spawns a new process, that new process will get a new PID and its PPID will be your process; in other words, your process will be the parent and the new process will be the child. That's how it works. The only way around this is get some other process (like `launchd`) to start a process for you, in which case `launchd` will be its PPID. But you're getting hung up on this whole "parent/child" thing; it's not important and child processes can continue running long after the parent has terminated. How else can shell scripts start servers?

Comment: As I said, you are trying to explain something I did not ask for. `The only way around this is get some other process (like launchd) to start a process for you` -> This is exactly what I am trying to do, as I explained, but it does not work using `NSWorkspace`!

Comment: No, I'm trying to figure out why you think you need to start a process that isn't a child of your process. You describe it as *"a short-lived process that executes one thing and exits immediately"*, so why can't that be a child of your process?

Comment: Footnote: `Process`, `NSWorkspace`, et. al. are just frameworks and therefor execute code in your process; anything they spawn will be on behalf of your process, and therefor they can only create child processes.

Comment: Because I need to emulate the behavior of `git-difftool` and external difftools depend on the command exiting immediately to signify the session has ended and taking the process information from the parent if any, for the `git.difftool.cmd` to correctly run.

Comment: Then I'm really confused because you said you were just trying to launch `bash`. Are you trying to implement a diff tool that's invoked by `git-difftool`? Are you trying to launch a new executable who's PPID is your process' PPID? That is not possible (IMNSOHO, but I'd love to hear from someone who thinks it is!).

Comment: `Are you trying to launch a new executable who's PPID is your process' PPID` no I'm not, and frankly I am tired of explaining myself over and over again and you not understanding what I need. It's really not that hard to understand if you would just read the question for once... launching a cli tool via `launchd`... whats there not to understand...

Comment: `man launchd`, `man launchctl`, and `man launchd.plist`; but that's not what `launched` is for and setting this up is going to be a lot of work, and I seriously doubt it will solve your problem. Basically, you have to create a plist file the describes the task, then register it with launchd (`launchctl bootstrap <domain> <plist>`), then let launchd run it. (cont)

Comment: ... and you need to somehow arrange for it not to run again (probably using the `KeepAlive` property), then figure out how to tell that your process has finished, then remove the plist and unregister your service (`launchctrl unload ...`) because `launchd` is for persistent services, not one-off executions. Good luck!

Comment: already solved it..... `c helper tool` > `fork`/`setsid` > `ppid=1` > done